# JMS - How to correctly implement message receiver with explicit acknowledge?

Tags: java, jms

The JMS API is driving me to the point of a mental breakdown.. What is the correct way to poll messages of a jms queue and explicitly acknowledge that each message has been processed correctly?

Should I create a "transacted session" and which acknowledge mode is the correct one in the scenario described above?

My design constraints:

1. Duplicate delivery is no problem
2. Performance is not a major concern
3. Dropping messages on the floor is not acceptable
4. I'd rather not add a dependency to Spring-JMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 types of message acknowledgement types in JMS:

`DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE` - Automatic but a delayed acknowledgement of messages by the session that may result in duplicate messages if JMS provider fails.

`AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` - Session automatically acknowledges when a message is delivered to application

`CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` - Client application explicitly acknowledges messages.

For your requirement I think you can choose `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` as it allows your application to explicitly acknowledge messages. But you must note that in some JMS providers, acknowledging a consumed message automatically acknowledges the receipt of all messages that have been delivered by its session. However some JMS providers do implement a per message acknowledgement.

The other option you have is to use a transacted session where acknowledge mode has no effect. In a transacted session, messages are removed from a queue only when application calls `commit`. If the session calls `rollback` or ends without calling `commit`, all messages that were delivered to an application since the previous `commit` call will reappear in the queue.